# Are unresettable "flags" threadsafe in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous, thread-safety

I have been using this pattern for a while, but I only recently came to think that it might not be OK to do this. Basically, I use some variant of this pattern:

```
public class SampleJavaAsync
{
    public SampleJavaAsync() { }

    private boolean completed;
    public void start()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //... do something on a different thread
                completed = true;
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void update()
    {
        if (!completed) return;
        //... do something else
    }
}
```

*The user is responsible for making sure `start` is only called once. `update` is called wherever and whenever.

I've always assumed this is threadsafe in Java, because even though nothing is strictly synchronized, I only ever set `completed` to true. Once it has been observed to be `true`, it will not reset to `false`. It is initialized to false in the constructor, which is by definition thread safe (unless you do something stupid in it). So, is it thread safe to use unresettable flags in this way? (And if so, does it even provide any performance benefits?)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java: it's feasible for update() to not see the update to completed that has already happened.   Unless you mark it volatile, the JVM is permitted to do all sorts of things in the name of optimization (namely reordering reads and writes as it sees fit), meaning you could feasibly hit a state where the thread running update() NEVER sees that completed has changed, because it's not marked volatile, and it thinks it can optimize away that pesky write (or defer it).

You would at least run the risk of having inconsistency when it's first set, where, e.g. a call to update() on the same thread could see a different value than the same call from another thread, at the same time.

Better explained:

http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html

Or, if you're really curious about concurrency in Java, buy a copy of JCIP:

http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/